# Revoke Access token of one application then other access token in other system also goes undefined

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

My application is using authentication of google api .So I checked both scenarios in Google Auth Playground but it is creating the same problem

> Scenario - 1 [ Different browser but same machine ]

My application is running in two different browsers **Google chrome** incognito and **Mozilla Firefox**

I was wondering when I saw that after revoking access token through my application inside Google chrome window, Automatically makes access token **INVALID** of application inside Mozilla browser.

Three screenshot to describe the problem

1.Get drive files using access token- mozilla firefox
[image]

2.Revoke access token from Google Chrome
[image: 2.Revoke access token from Google Chrome]

3.Again fetching files after revoking access token from other browser
[image: Again fectch files after revoking access token from other browser]

> Scenario - 2 [ Different browser and different machine ]

Same thing is happening when I am using two **Different System** with **same account** to authenticate buth using ouath playground both system has their own access token and refresh token but when you revoke access token from one system, Automatically other system's access token goes undefined.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: It's a single Google account for all requests?

Comment: @abraham yes its a same google account

Answer (score 0):

[Revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

> In some cases a user may wish to revoke access given to an application. A user can revoke access by visiting Account Settings. It is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it.

The revoke request removes the apps access from the account so all requests from that app to that account should fail until authorization is granted again.

Comment: I want to revoke it because my application is based on client side language and so that next time when user do login He will be able to do login again using any google account.. problem is If i will not do revoke on logout next time user will be able to login again through same account .. without revoke he can not use another account..